# C++ : Pick portions/data from a string having fixed format

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have a string with some fixed format. Let's say :

> This is **24** day of **Aug** of **2016**

So, is there a simple way in C++ (similar to `strtol` in C), so that I can extract the data into variables as below :

```
day = 24;
month = "Aug";
year = 2016;
```

Comment: @NathanOliver, why regex?  What not `substr()`?  The OP mentions that it is a `string` and has a `fixed format`.

Comment: @BatCoder Oh yeah. Retracted comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).  You can load the string into the `stringstream` and then read it into the variables that you want.  It will do the conversions for you into the data types that you are using.  For example you could use

```
std::string input = "This is 24 day of Aug of 2016";
std::stringstream ss(input)
std::string eater; // used to eat non needed input
std::string month;
int day, year;
ss >> eater >> eater >> day >> eater >> eater >> month >> eater >> year;
```

It looks a little verbose but now you don't need to use `find` and `substr` and conversion functions.

Comment: @InsaneCoder I try to make my variables names mean something and to me `eater` is just something that is used to consume unneeded input and can be trash can of sorts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [substr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) function.

Sample code snippet as below:

```
string str = "This is 24 day of Aug of 2016";

std::string day = str.substr (8,2);     //day = 24
std::string month = str.substr (18,3);  //month = Aug
std::string year = str.substr (25,4);   //year = 2016
```

The first parameter of `substr()` is the `start position` of the substring; while the second parameter specifies the `number of characters to be read` from that position.